# finding exception "unrecognized selector sent to instance" only occurs in iOS6

Tags: ios, ios6, unrecognized-selector

I am getting an exception in my iPhone-app,

```
-[__NSCFString sizeWithAttributes:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance,
```

when I start my app uner iOS6.1, under iOS7 or higher everything is OK.
The only difference between iOS6 and higher in my project are the XIBs. The error occurs when I press a button. 
Maybe it comes from the different XIB, maybe not.

It looks like a memory leak, but i cant figure out why it happens.
The Exception occurrs when is try to calculate the size of a text from a button.

I set Exception-breakpoints to find the error. 
Here some infos from the stacktrace:

In this method the error occurs:

```
- (float) calculateButtonWidth:(TypeButtonRest*) typeButtonRest{

    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
    NSDictionary *userAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: font,
                     NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor]};
    const CGSize textSize = [[typeButtonRest text] sizeWithAttributes: userAttributes];
    ...
```

The method is called from here:

```
- (ButtonMatrixInfos*) calculateButtonSchema:(NSMutableArray*) buttons screenWidth:(double)screenWidth minMargin:(double)minMargin{
    ButtonMatrixInfos *returnValue = [[[ButtonMatrixInfos class] alloc] init];
    int buttonCount = [buttons count];
    [buttons retain];
    for (int i=0; i < buttonCount; i++) {
        float curWidth = [self calculateButtonWidth:[buttons objectAtIndex:i]];
        maxButtonWidth = curWidth > maxButtonWidth ? curWidth : maxButtonWidth;
    }
    ...
```

My assumption is, that `buttons` is corrupted. They are coming from here:

```
-(RadioButtonContainer*)addRadioButtons:(NSMutableArray *)buttons withButtonGroupName:(NSString*) groupName andMarginLeft:(int) marginLeft andMarginRight:(int) marginRight preselected:(NSString*) preselected {
ButtonListLayouter *bll = [[[[ButtonListLayouter class] alloc] init]retain];   
ButtonMatrixInfos *bmi = [bll calculateButtonSchema:buttons screenWidth:(screenSize.width - marginLeft - marginRight) minMargin:5];
...
```

Created here:

```
NSMutableArray *buttonsRest = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]retain];
for (int i=0; i < [buttons count]; i++) {
    TypeButtonRest *tpr = [[[[TypeButtonRest class] alloc] init]retain];
    tpr.text = [[buttons objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"value"];
    tpr.key = [[buttons objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"key"];
    [buttonsRest addObject:tpr];
}
```

I hope this codefragments can help.

best regards

Comment: Oh nice, thanks. Is there a equivalent to it in iOS6?

Answer (score 3):

`sizeWithAttributes` is only available starting at iOS 7.0. You want to use `sizeWithFont` in iOS 6. Read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont:)